# ExtJs Field Container Stretch

Tags: extjs, layout, extjs6-classic

I'm using ExtJs 6.
How can I achieve to have the layout of a `FieldContainer`, to act exactly like the form layout.

See my fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/15v5

I would like that the size of my `textfield` which are in the `FieldContainer` has exactly the same size of the first `textfield`.

Please also not that I put `textfield` inside my `FieldContainer` but I want the same think for every type of `component` to my be in the `FieldContainer`.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change layout of your form panel

```
Ext.application({
    name : 'Fiddle',

    launch : function() {
       Ext.create({
            xtype: 'panel',
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            items: {
                padding: 5,
                xtype: 'form',
                layout: {
                            type:'vbox', 
                            align:'stretch'
                        },
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'textfield',
                        fieldLabel: 'Name'
                    }, {
                        xtype: 'fieldcontainer',
                        fieldLabel: 'Test',
                        layout: 'form',
                        //layout: {
                        //    type:'vbox', 
                        //    align:'stretch'
                        //},
                        // combineLabels: true,
                        items: [
                            {
                                itemId: "in",
                                xtype: 'textfield'
                            }, {
                                itemId: "in2",
                                xtype: 'textfield'
                            }
                        ]
                    }, {
                        xtype: 'fieldcontainer',
                        fieldLabel: 'Test2',
                        layout: 'form',
                        //layout: {
                        //    type:'vbox', 
                        //    align:'stretch'
                        //},
                        // combineLabels: true,
                        items: [
                            {
                                xtype: 'component',
                                style: {
                                    border: '1px solid red'
                                },
                                html: 'something'
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        })
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I'will also change the layout of the fieldContainer to be perfect.